# Como colocar un botón centrado verticalmente en la pagina que me lleve al final de ella?

Tags: bootstrap, botón

Un gran saludo.

Me gustaría saber como hacer para colocar un botón centrado verticalmente en la página que me lleve al footer o final de ella. El botón es una imagen deseo que este fijo encima de otro contenido, el proyecto lo estoy haciendo con Bootstrap.

Anexo una imagen para explicarme mejor, muchisimas gracias por ayudarme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Quieres que el boton esté fijo, siempre a la misma altura y por encima de todo lo demás?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui un ejemplo: este usa el boton como enlace y recibe un href para ir al id de cualquier elemento que gustes. Con un poco de javascript puedes ocultar el botton cuando se presiona, y al hacer scroll volver a mostrar el botton, es solo una idea.(En el segundo ejemplo puedes ver esa opcion)

```css
div{
    height:800px;
    text-align:center;
}

.blue{
    background:lightblue;
}

.green{
    background:lightgreen;
}
.red{
    background:red;

}

button{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue" id="blue">
    <h2>header</h2>
    <a href="#red"><button>button</button></a>
</div>
<div class="green" id="green">
    <h2>2nd header</h2>
</div>
<div class="red" id="red">
    <h2>3 header</h2>
</div>
```

Aqui un ejemplo:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>

<div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:30px">Scroll Down</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgrey;padding:30px 30px 2500px">This example demonstrates how to create a "scroll to top" button that becomes visible when the user starts to scroll the page.</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Espero esto te sirva, y lo puedas aplicar a lo que gustes.

Comment: Muchisisimas gracias :), es exactamente lo que necesitaba, gracias por ayudarme, ahora solo tengo una pequeña pregunta, mira que el botón no que queda en el centro de la pagina sino más bien ubicado al costado izquierdo.